# Can I remove or rename to a non unique value the instance label in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I've tried the following:

- setting it to a fixed value in relabel configs with the following block:

```
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: my_custom_(.+)
    target_label: instance
    replacement: 'no-instance'
```

This made no difference.

- with setting it to a fixed value via `metric_relabel_configs`

```
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: my_custom_(.+)
    target_label: instance
    replacement: 'no-instance'
```

This made a difference, but the metric ingestion broke. The flat lines are not flat, they increase only a little bit over the time. But when all the metrics had instance label as 'no-instance' it didn't become a single line continuously increasing.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sanely, you need each target's labels to be unique so that metrics from different targets don't clash and the `instance` label is the way to do that.

Comment: Yeah. I think that would need an intermediate reduce. Thanks!